# What is the JavaScript "idiomatic" way of settling a promise externally?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

In a program I've found the concept of an externally settlable promise (for lack of better word) useful. The use case is: Some value is required multiple places in the program but is calculated asynchronously one particular place (as part of other work). So the idea is to up-front define e.g. a global variable to hold a promise for the value:

let variable = settlablePromise();

(where settlablePromise is a utility function - see below).

Whereever the value is required we can simply .then or await on the variable (since it has been assigned a promise).

THe place in the program that calculates the value will call variable.settle(x) where x is the calculated value.

This scheme works but I am wondering if there is a more standard way of doing it, rather than this "settlablePromise" function, seen below. It's function is to produce a promise that is externally settlable:

```
function settlablePromise()
{
    let resolver = null;
    let p = new Promise( (resolv,err) => {
        resolver  = resolv;
    });
    p.settle = function(v)
    {
        resolver(v);
    };
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I think you're trying to describe the [deferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred) pattern. It can be useful in testing, but you'd probably need to give more context to say whether what you're doing here is sensible.

Comment: It is called "deferred". It is considered to be an anti-pattern because it treats promises as a fancy callback system. But if you need it for some reason then your code looks OK.

Answer (score 2):

> This scheme works but I am wondering if there is a more standard way of doing it

Largely, the answer is: Don't. :-) Instead, do this:

```
const variable = xyz();
```

...and make `xyz` the part of the code that can do the work of getting the value, rather than having that code call `variable.settle(x)` later. The problem with exposing the settlement methods is that they they can be called by any code, potentially more than once, but only the **first** one called will have an effect on the promise. So the design **intentionally** makes those private to the code creating the promise. The promise is meaningless without some asynchronous operation having been started that it can report the completion of.

If the code that will do the asynchronous work isn't ready to start the work right away, you can still have `xyz` return a promise and have that code start the process later. The settlement methods would remain private to that code, rather than being exposed to all the code, maintaining encapsulation.

It's a rare use case, normally you want to start the work when you create the promise. But in that rare case, you can do it without exposing the settlement functions.

For instance:

```js
// In a module specific to the asynchronous work
let [promise, start] = (() => {
    let start;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        start = () => {
            // ...Actually start the work, handle completion by calling
            // `resolve` or `reject...
        };
    });
    return [promise, start];
})();
export function xyz() { // The public face of the work
    return promise;
}

// Code elsewhere in the module starts the process via `start`
```

You might even expose the promise directly rather than making it the result of a function call:

```js
// In a module specific to the asynchronous work
let [promiseOfNiftyStuff, start] = (() => {
    let start;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        start = () => {
            // ...Actually start the work, handle completion by calling
            // `resolve` or `reject...
        };
    });
    return [promise, start];
})();
export { promiseOfNiftyStuff };

// Code elsewhere in the module starts the process via `start`
```

Again, it's a rare use case though.

[Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) was kind enough to provide a great example of that "rare" use case where you need to leak the settlement handler to the containing context, and still keeping it well encapsulated (in this case to `fromEvent`):

```js
async function* fromEvent(element, event) {
    let resolve = null;

    element.addEventListener(event, (event) => {
        resolve(event);
    });

    while (true) {
        yield new Promise(r => {
            resolve = r;
        })
    }
}

async function run() {
    const button = document.getElementById('test');

    for await (const event of fromEvent(button, 'click')) {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}

run();
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

Comment: I found it surprisingly common when trying to do things using async generators. For example to stream DOM events https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/98nvdk0s/7/ one kinda had to leak resolve to upper scope to only add listener once. :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - Yeah, it definitely happens. Your code is a great practical example of when it can happen and how to keep things contained when it does. Nothing outside of `fromEvent` can try to settle the promise, so it's not a free-for-all. :-)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - So good, in fact, I put it in the answer and marked the answer a CW. :-) Thanks!